# Loading embedded scripts through jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to have a jQuery UI dialog box that pops up and shows a basic form, which also includes an external javascript file.

The modal pops up, but none of the script contents load. Not sure why. If I go directly to the page the modal is loading, it works fine.

Modal content:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.bankrate.com/free-content/css/bankrate-fcc-calculators.css" type="text/css"/>

<input id="mrtgCal" type ="text" value="1,Arial,600" style="display:none" />

<script language="Javascript" src="http://js.bankrate.com/free-calculators/free-simple-mortgage-calculator-widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">mrtgCalcinit();</script>
```

Modal call:

```
$(function(){
        $('.modal-popup a, .email-button a').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #region-content')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 600,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    show: "fade",
                    hide: "fade",
                    closeText: 'X'

                });
            $link.click(function(){
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false;
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The scripts are not running because of the way you're calling `.load()`.  The library will not run embedded scripts when you use a selector after the URL. By that I mean the addition of `' #region-content'` to the end of the "href" value.

Why?  I don't completely know; I suspect it has something to do with the fact that jQuery doesn't know whether the embedded `<script>` bodies rely on scripts in the `<head>` (or elsewhere) to work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) wont load the scripts (read the Script Execution section). However it is not necesary to extend the dialog, you can use `.delegate()`, `.on()` or even a very to use plugin called [liveplugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) to manage the dynamic content loaded into the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The best variant is to write your custom jquery ui widget, extending jquery ui dialog with your functionality.